# convert number from cell to double, cell2mat not working

Tags: matlab

I think I'm losing my mind.

I have a 3 x 2 cell which looks exactly like below.

```
 Region  Code
 US      1
 EU      2
```

I then have the following code to determine the row number for the EU region.

```
eq_code_index = find(ismember(fund.type_des(:, 1), 'EU'));
eq_code = cell2mat(fund.type_des(eq_code_index, 2));
```

eq_code_index returns 3 which is correct (row headers are included in the output). So I want the value in row 3, column 2 which is 2. I then use cell2mat to convert it from a cell value to an integer however it doesn't work the value is of type char? Haven't a clue why cell2mat isn't working?

**Update**

Even if I do the following two lines of code below I can't get the codes into a vector, they turn into char's

```
codes = fund.type_des(2:end, end);
codes = cell2mat(codes)
```

Comment: I cant very well replicate this without more code, but the first thing that comes to mind is that you *cannot*  use `cell2mat` on your initial cell, since it contains multiple classes. The other thing: it seems `eq_code` is calling to a single cell. Use `str2num` in that case instead of `cell2mat`. If it is a number, as it seems like above, you are calling a number with `fund.type_des(eq_code_index, 2)`, which is not a cell-object, thus MATLAB will throw you an error.

Comment: Print the actual error you are getting. Also, print the results of the following: `class(fund.type_des{2, 2})` (note the curly braces). If possible, show how you get the cell array in the first place.

Comment: I'm not actually getting an error. It's just that eq_code should be a number but is instead a 2 x 1 char

Comment: And `class(fund.type_des{2, 2})` is ....?

Comment: the answer it prints class(fund.type_des{2,1}) is char

Comment: As a general rule of thumb do not put headers in cells.  If you want headers use tables or structs instead of cells.  In your case the entire cell was read in as characters.  You need to change your import script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a single element in a cell array, use curly braces:

```
fund.type_des{eq_code_index, 2};
```

This is generally simpler than using `cell2mat()`. If the contents of the cell are chars and you want an integer, you have to perform the conversion. `str2num()` is one of many options for this:

```
eq_code = str2num(fund.type_des{eq_code_index, 2});
```